# want to fetch multiple details from database if value is selected in selected tag

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have a table 'class' with thier fee structure. i want to show fee amount if a particular class is selected by user. 
i'm able to fetch only one value from database want ot show multiple value..

here is my db table:

[image]

here are my codes:-

fetch.js

```
$('#class').click(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'fetch2.php',
        'class=' + $('#class').val(),
        function(result){
            $('#tution_fee').empty();
            $.each(result.result, function(){
                $('#tution_fee').append('<option>'+this['tution_fee']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    );
});
```

fetch.php

```
<?php 
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD','');
define('DB','bethel');

$con    = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);
$class  = $_GET['class'];
$sql    = "SELECT tution_fee FROM class WHERE class='$class'";
$res    = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($result, 
        array('tution_fee'=>$row[0])
    );
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

first one is `fetch.js` and second  `fetch.php`

here you can see the JS code that one value can be fetched from database but i want to fetch multiple value.

please help

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You only get one column from the database since you've only defined one column in your query: `SELECT tution_fee`. If you want more columns, just define them in the select: `SELECT tution_fee, column2, column3`... and so on.

Comment: plz help me with array